# c++ and VS2010 - No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have an annoying problem while debugging my applications using VS2010.

I got

> "No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed"

for some functions (seems in a random way). Furthermore, it is not possible to show the disassembly too.

The funny is that this problem occurs only when using x64 configuration. The debugging on 32-bit works properly.

We have alle the .PDBs stored correctly.

Is someone having an idea?

Comment: Are your Build\Advanced Build Settings the same for 32 and 64 bits?

Comment: Just a quick guess: PDBs might be compiled on some configuration other then x64 so you might need to build PDBs for x64 configuration in order to debug properly. If you've already did so then re-check your PDB's path in project configuration.

Comment: Yes, we have both pdbs compiled in both configurations, and they are in different paths. Which advanced settings are you talking about Float2011?

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to IIS
2. Application Pools
3. Select the application pool in use
4. Right => Advanced settings...
5. Enable 32-Bit Applications = **TRUE**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure [/Oy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kxx5t2c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) "Omit Frame Pointer" commandline option is not set, also some functions can be missing in the callstack if they were inlined. You can disable inlining with [/Ob0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47238hez%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) option